# gridmvc not showing data from database

Tags: c#, mvcgrid

I am able to get my grid to show up but cannot get my data to populate inside of the cells. Here is my grid and it looks perfect.

```
public static class MVCGridConfig 
{
    public static void RegisterGrids()
    {
        

        MVCGridDefinitionTable.Add("Report_Actions", new MVCGridBuilder<FMB_Reports_AllInfo_Result>()
            .WithAuthorizationType(AuthorizationType.AllowAnonymous)
            .AddColumns(cols =>
            {
                // Add your columns here
                cols.Add("Id").WithSorting(true)
                    .WithValueTemplate("<div><label>ID:</label>{Model1.PickupPath}")
                    .WithHeaderText("User ID").WithHtmlEncoding(false)
                    .WithValueExpression(p => p.Id.ToString()); // use the Value Expression to return the cell text for this column
                cols.Add("PickupPath").WithColumnName("File Location")
                    .WithValueTemplate("{Model.PickupPath}")
                    .WithHeaderText("File Locations")
                    .WithValueExpression(p => p.PickupPath);
                cols.Add("ReportDescription").WithColumnName("Report Name")
                    .WithHeaderText("Report Name")
                    .WithValueExpression(p => p.ReportDescription);
                cols.Add("DropOffPath").WithColumnName("File Destination")
                    .WithHeaderText("File Destination")
                    .WithValueExpression(p => p.DropOffPath);
                cols.Add("Active").WithColumnName("Active")
                    .WithHeaderText("Active")
                    .WithValueExpression(p => p.Active.ToString());
                cols.Add("TimeAccessed").WithColumnName("Time Accessed")
                    .WithHeaderText("Time Accessed")
                    .WithValueExpression(p => p.TimeAccessed.ToString());
                

            })
            //.WithNoResultsMessage("<div class='pad-left-20'>There are no items.</div>")
            .WithPaging(true, 30)
            .WithRetrieveDataMethod((context) =>
            {
                var options = context.QueryOptions;
                var result = new QueryResult<FMB_Reports_AllInfo_Result>();
              
                return new QueryResult<FMB_Reports_AllInfo_Result>()
                {
                    Items = new List<FMB_Reports_AllInfo_Result>(),
                    TotalRecords = 0 // if paging is enabled, return the total number of records of all pages

                };

            })
        );
        
    }
}
```

But my data does not show in the columns. I have follwed the guides from the mvcgrid website and this is all it shows that I should need to do to get my data in here.  Here is my HTML:

```
@using MVCGrid.Web;
```

```
<div class="panel-body">

    @Html.MVCGrid("Report_Actions")

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im only answering this myself because I finally found out the main issue as to why my data wasn't showing and it was dumb. So hopefully this will find someone fancy in a couple years or months if someone does the same thing.

```
cols.Add("Id").WithSorting(true)
                .WithValueTemplate("<div><label>ID:</label>{Model1.PickupPath}")
                .WithHeaderText("User ID").WithHtmlEncoding(false)
                .WithValueExpression(p => p.Id.ToString()); // use the Value
```

In the .WithValueTemplate() I deleted the div and labels and everything worked perfect. I wasn't referencing the right stuff so it wasn't throwing an error but it would just stop on this when debugging.